# UWP app samples provided by Microsoft not compiling on VS2017

Tags: uwp

I followed this [Microsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-uwp-app-samples) to deploy and run their UWP samples on `VS2017` but they always gives me the error shown in the image below. For example I tried to run `CustomEditControl` sample in `VS2017` on `Windows 10` and followed their following instructions from `README.md` but it still gives me the same error:

**Question**: Can someone from Microsoft team or anyone who has successfully run any of these samples help me PLEASE?

**From their README.md file**:

```
## Run the sample

The next steps depend on whether you just want to deploy the sample or you want to both deploy and run it.

### Deploying the sample

- Select Build > Deploy Solution. 

### Deploying and running the sample

- To debug the sample and then run it, press F5 or select Debug >  Start Debugging. To run the sample without debugging, press Ctrl+F5 or selectDebug > Start Without Debugging.
```

**ERROR**:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

1. I'm using `Windows 10 Pro` with latest `version 1809`
2. `VS2017` has latest update `15.9.5`
3. I took the sample from `CS` folder that means it is a C# app. The sample builds `successfully` when using `Build-->Rebuild Solution` menu. The output shows as follows:

   > > 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CustomEditControl, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
   > >     1>  CustomEditControl -> C:\DotNET2017\UWP\Official_samples\Windows-universal-samples-master\Samples\CustomEditControl\cs\bin\ARM\Debug\CustomEditControl.exe
   > >     ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
4. By following the instructions from `README.md` if I run `Build-->Deploy Solution`, it gives me the error `Deploy failed` with no reasons/causes. Moreover, the `Error List` tab at the bottom of `VS2017` shows 0 errros as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You did not quote the first step which was "Build the sample". Did it build successfully? If not, what were the errors?

Comment: With VS 2017 you need to select the workload **Universal Windows Platform development**, but in order to build C++ UWP apps you must also select the optional component "C++ Tools for UWP apps". See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017). Look for an application on your system called "Visual Studio Installer" to update your installation.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn After reading your comments, I've added an `UPDATE` section to answer your inquiry. After reading the UPDATE please let me know what I may still be missing since I do think I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've updated, the problem is that you built the "ARM" Platform. Since your system is not a [Windows on ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/) device, that will not deploy locally.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CustomEditControl,
Configuration: Debug ARM <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEM RIGHT HERE
```

Try selecting either "x86" or "x64" as your Platform and retry.

> Yes, it's annoying that the default is "ARM" or "ARM64" for these projects, but that's lexicographical order for you...

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you for helping me (and probably many more readers of your response).

Answer (score 1):

Go on the drop-down box in the toolbar, where you can choose the output type, (debug/release etc...),

Expand that, and click on 'Configuration Manager', make sure your main project has both the 'Build' and the 'Deploy' Checkboxes checked.

Those samples usually come with those unchecked.

Also make sure you use 'Any Cpu' output instead of 'ARM'

Comment: Per your suggestion I verified that both 'Build' and the 'Deploy' Checkboxes were already checked when I had opened the project. Moreover, for this sample, there is no `Any Cpu` option in the dropdown you are talking about. The only options available are: `ARM, x64, and x32`. Thank you for trying to help. Please keep up the good work at such a young age.

Comment: "Any CPU" is an option for classic desktop .NET applications because it uses platform-agnostic IL. For UWP apps including .NET-based ones, it has to be a platform-specific target for packaging and because the code is compiled with [Roslyn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703435.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).